# Can SELECT FOR UPDATE cause deadlocks?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I am using Django 2.2.12 as an ORM for MySQL 8.0, one of the queries is a concurrent `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, inside a transaction, where two or more threads may be targeting the same rows. Is not select for update atomic? Two transactions are allowed to lock and select the rows at same time? I am getting deadlock errors at random times.

Comment: Yes it can cause Deadlocks. Why dont you yust go for a higher Transaction Level and avoid the Deadlocks?

Comment: @NoahResch how? isolation level?